# Why "name" doesn't work in kmem_cache_create function

Tags: linux-kernel

Cache named "filp" is created in function files_init() according to Linux kernel source code. files_init() is marked as __init. However, when I debug kernel I find this cache is actually named as "kmalloc-256". Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I'd like to answer this question myself. 
In function kmem_cache_create(), a function named __kmem_cache_alias() will be invoked to see if we can have an mergeable kmem_cache suitable. In the case of file, kmalloc-256 is the mergeable kmem_cache.